# How do I optimize PDF based Question-Answering application to deliver the answer much quicker? Cannot figure out what is taking up so much time

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to create a Streamlit application that allows me to upload PDFs to a specific directory and perform Question-Answering and return answers based on the PDFs. I have saved the Faiss Vector Database in a local directory from where I import the embedding database.

```
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Home",
)
def Home():
    st.title("Dashboard")

    st.markdown(
        '''
    Choose the user type for specific tasks
    1. User: Query LLM
    2. Admin: Add PDFs to source directory
    '''
    )
    
def User():
    
    from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
    from langchain.llms import GPT4All
    from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
    from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=r"all-MiniLM-L6-v2 embeddings being loaded")
    llm = GPT4All(
        model = r'ggml-model-gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.bin'
    )
    faiss = FAISS.load_local(r'Path to faissDB local file',embeddings=embeddings)
    print("LLM model and faiss db initialized")        

    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff") 

    def answerLLM(query):
        similar_docs = faiss.similarity_search(query)
        print(similar_docs)
        print("The result from LLM model is: ")  
        return chain.run(input_documents=similar_docs, question=query)

    st.title("PDF based Question and Answering")
    query = st.text_input("Please enter your query: ")
    answer = answerLLM(query=query)
    st.subheader(answer)

def Admin():
    # admin to add new pdfs
    import os
    import streamlit as st

    st.title("Admin")
    # pdfPath = st.text_input("Please enter the PDF to be added:  ")
    destPath = r'Path to the diretory where PDFs are stored'

    st.subheader("Choose .pdf file to upload: ")
    file = st.file_uploader('',type="pdf")    #error handling done by streamlit

    if file is not None:
        fileName = file.name
        save_path = os.path.join(destPath,fileName)
        with open(save_path, mode='wb') as w:
            w.write(file.getvalue())
        if os.path.exists(save_path):
            st.subheader("File added to directory")


page_names_to_funcs = {
    "Home": Home,
    "User": User,
    "Admin": Admin
}

demo_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select a user type", page_names_to_funcs.keys())
page_names_to_funcs[demo_name]()
```

What I want is to improve the time taken to deliver the answer. In isolation, the answer itself is fine but it takes way too long for it to be usable. In User(), I have tried to run all the main time consuming command in isolation. The import commands are time consuming in itself as well as the loading of the local GPT4All model. But the main culprit seems to be the answerLLM() function. This takes up a lot of time.

Also, it seems everytime query the User() function it reinitializes the model. Ideally, I want it to load the model only once and query it multiple times without much delay.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.